# how to update scope value after 5 sec in constructor typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, constructor

I am facing a problem in which I have to refresh the scope value after 5 sec. Here's my controller constructor function where I initialize the value and call the timeout function to refresh the content after 5 sec.

```
static $inject = ['$scope', 'selectedCardAccount', 'CardService', 'ecAnimationService', '$interval', '$modal','$rootScope','$timeout','PromiseTimeout','$q','$stateParams'];
            constructor(public $scope,public selectedCardAccount, public CardService:services.CardService, public $interval:ng.IIntervalService, public $modal,public $rootScope:ng.IRootScopeService, public $timeout,public PromiseTimeout,public $q,public TrackPendingRequest,public $stateParams) {

    //setting the current value
    this.account = selectedCardAccount.account;

    //calling a serive again after five section to referesh the content
    $timeout(function(){
            //delete the current object
        delete this.account;
        //calling service to get result
                CardService.getAccountAndCardByShortName($stateParams.productShortName,$stateParams.id).then((succRess)=>{

            //setting the value
            //Error : cannot read property of account
            this.account = succRess.account;
        });
    }, 5000);
}
```

**Error : cannot read property of account**

**Directive code :**

```
module ec.directives {
        export class easein{
            /**
             * A directive is not new:ed up so we don´t specify anything on this class
             * */
            constructor(){
                var directive: ng.IDirective = {};
                directive.link = (scope:IEaseInNumberScope, element, attrs, ctrl:controllers.EaseInNumberCtrl) => {
                    ctrl.animateRemainingValue(scope);
                };
                directive.restrict = "EA";
                directive.template = "{{current | number : 2}}";
                directive.controller = 'EaseInNumberCtrl';
                directive.scope = {
                    duration: "=?",
                    startValue: "=?",
                    endValue: "="
                };

                return directive;
            }
        }
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h2 class="heading-small-bold light mar-l-1"
            ng-bind="'used_amount' | i18n"></h2>

        <h1 class="heading-big-thin-medium mar-l-1">
            <easein end-value="vm.account.usedCredit"></easein>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 align-r">
        <h2 class="heading-small-bold light mar-r-1"
            ng-bind="'left_to_spend' | i18n"></h2>

        <h1 class="heading-big-thin-medium mar-r-1">
            <easein start-value="vm.account.creditLimit"
                    end-value="vm.account.openToBuy"></easein>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 mar-t-2">
        <progressbar class="progress-bar" value="vm.loadingValue"
                     max="vm.account.creditLimit"
                     type="warning"></progressbar>
        <div class="flexible-header">
            <h2 class="heading-small-bold light"
                ng-bind="'last_transactions' | i18n"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if some one has any suggestion that how can I refresh the value after 5 section in constructor please help.

Comment: is that the real error that you get? Normally you get `cannot read property propName of whatever`. Could you put the line number where you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are mistakes in your approach.

First you need to use a lambda (arrow function) in Typescript so that the `this` context of the constructor is set correctly in the $timeout callback.

Second, the is no reason to use the delete keyword. Set the value of `this.account`with the new result while keeping the initial object reference constant.

```js
static $inject = ['$scope', 'selectedCardAccount', 'CardService', 'ecAnimationService', '$interval', '$modal','$rootScope','$timeout','PromiseTimeout','$q','$stateParams'];
constructor(public $scope,public selectedCardAccount, public CardService:services.CardService, public $interval:ng.IIntervalService, public $modal,public $rootScope:ng.IRootScopeService, public $timeout,public PromiseTimeout,public $q,public TrackPendingRequest,public $stateParams) {

    //setting the current value
    this.account = selectedCardAccount.account;

    //calling a serive again after five section to referesh the content
    $timeout(() => {

         CardService
             .getAccountAndCardByShortName($stateParams.productShortName,$stateParams.id)
             .then((succRess)=>{
                  angular.copy(succRess.account, this.account);
              });
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Now `this.account ` get updated but the value in view not changed. I have custom directive on view to show this value

Comment: That is because the reference to the initial object has changed. What is the type of `this.account` ? Keep the initial reference and update the properties that are important.

Comment: So what i have to do to update value of custom directive

Comment: I updated my answer. try using `angular.copy(succRess.account, this.account);`.

Comment: not it not working , I also tries to run $apply to update value but nothing got chqnaged

Comment: what does the `account` look like ? is it an array or an object ?

Comment: it's object with no of property like name,opentobuy and creditlimit etc

Comment: Hard to say. I suggest that you edit your snippet to make it run and reproduce your issue, including html template. It will then be easier for me (us) to investigate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, account is not available on succRess.

You should try to see if the succRess is a valid JSON object, if the service returns data as is from a server, it needs to be deserialized to JSON object using JSON.parse.

Also, you might want to consider using $timeout, so the change in value is perceived by the listeners of that property.

Comment: succRess is returning the proper object. what i just need to assigned that to this.account

Comment: do you see the account property on succRess object?